# What do these expressions mean and where can i read more?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to remove all the numbers inside an array which is constantly being modified, by googling i found this

```
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__';
str.replace(/#|_/g,''); // result: "this is a test"
```

Which is honestly just unreadeable, so any explanations of **(/#|_/g,'')** are welcome but i kept googling and also found this

```
let difference = arr1.filter(x => !arr2.includes(x));
```

which i think both do the exact same thing. Im new to JS, how do you read this? like im trying to understand it but in my head it says "filter x then if arr2 doesnt include x" and it just ends there...it seems incomplete, what happens if it doesnt include 'x'?? and also why should it include '*x*' shouldnt it be '*numbers*' considering '*numbers*' is an array with all numbers from 0 to 9. This is so confusing to read for me, and even though i can copypaste it i dont like not understanding what im using.

If anyone can explain these expressions i'll be very grateful, if not, at least a source of where i can read about this.. since i dont even know how its called!

Comment: The first one uses regular expressions (more info can be found here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/).  The second one simply uses JavaScript's own built-in array methods... you should be able to find their specific documentation easily enough on the MDN and elsewhere

Comment: You can do the same for removing numbers from a string with `str.replace(/\d/g, "")`. And no, I don't know why you think the first codeblock does the same thing as the second. They have entirely different things in entirely different contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example appears to be a RegEx (regular expression) test. `str.replace(/#|_/g,'')` means to replace # or _ (`#|_`) globally (`g`) with `''` nothing. Take a look at a site like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and read up on Regular Expressions. RegEx is an incredibly simple, yet powerful, way to match text.

The second example is a simple [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It filters on `arr1` and filters out items not in `arr2`. `filter` is essentially a `foreach` loop that returns items that evaluate to true. `x` is the argument, being the current array item. `x => !arr2.includes(x)` will only be true if `arr2` does not contain the current item.

A final note, the filter is using an arrow function, a function shorthand. Read up more on those [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the answer i was hoping for! i read about RegEx and now i understand it much better. The second one looks simpler but im still a little bit confused, i now understand what filter is  doing and that  "x => !arr2.include(x)" acts more as a condition, right?  but i still get confused by the use of 'x', its like an index which is constantly  changing to match the current array position?  So, filter reads ever position of arr2 using 'x' as an index for arr1 so if arr1[x] isnt contained by any position of arr2 it will send true....?

Comment: @ValentínSanabria You're most welcome! Pretty close on your observation. `arr1.filter` reads every position of `arr1`, whereas `arr2.includes` checks `arr2` each time to see if `arr1[x]` is in `arr2`. `!` means *not*. `.filter` will return a new array of items that evaluate as `true`. A bit of pseudo-code (plain English to better understand code) might help here. Think of it as `x => if arr1[x] is not in arr2, add the current item to the return array`.

Comment: thank you dude i understand it perfectly now.. you explain so well, i would sub to a yt channel of you doing tutorials.